# How to use the method DeserializeJSON in a ColdFusion file

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I have this code: I got an error on page when execute this code. I am trying to figure out how does it look an object that is being deserialized from DeserializeJSON() method and I wrote this simple scenario but it doesn't work. Anyone see what the problem is in here?

```
<cfset test = '[{"phone":"1001106672","label4":"12","hcats":"18","freshStart":"0","phoneCode":"","hproduct":"12","checked":false},{"phone":"1001106672","label4":"test","hcats":"54","freshStart":"0","phoneCode":"456","hproduct":"15","checked":false}]'>

<cfset test2 =  DeserializeJSON(test)/>

<cfoutput>#test2#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Tip: *I got an error* That phrase should always be followed by the error message itself :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to cfoutput a complex object.  Try:`<cfdump var="#test2#">`
instead.

Comment: Thanks that was problem. I realized that the object returned is an array so now I know how to access values from there :)  @Chip thank you